# JAVA JUNG - How to add multiple Edge in Forest class

Tags: java, graph, jung

I am using JUNG to construct a graph, but i can't add extra edges to my graph. how can i add extra edges to my graph in Forest class?
here my code

```
public class BalloonLayoutDemo {

// Code borrowed from JUNG's demos

Factory<String> edgeFactory = new Factory<String>() {
    int i = 1;
    public String create() {
        System.out.println(i);
        return Integer.toString(i++);
    }
};

Forest<String, String> createTree(Forest<String, String> graph) {
    String base = "Base Node";
    graph.addEdge(edgeFactory.create(), base, "B0");
    graph.addEdge(edgeFactory.create(), base, "B1");
    graph.addEdge(edgeFactory.create(), base, "B2");
    graph.addEdge(edgeFactory.create(), base, "C1");
    graph.addEdge(edgeFactory.create(), base, "C1");
    graph.addEdge(edgeFactory.create(), base, "C1");

    return graph;
}
```

}

Comment: Please add your essential parts of the code to the question instead of linking it.

Comment: What do you mean by "extra" edges?  Please be more specific.